# Rename Debian package automatically pulled by apt-get upgrade

Tags: debian, repository, dpkg, replace

I have installed `package_a` with version 1.0. How to configure package control script for `package_b` (e.g version 1.1) to automatically replace package_a?

tried (as described in [7.6.2](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html)):

```
Package: package_b
Version: 1.1 
Conflicts: package_a
Provides: package_a
Replaces: package_a
```

with and without version (<< 1.1, on Replaces and Conflicts) but with no success.

Package is in repository and `apt-get install package_b` works as expected. But package will not detected as an upgrade.

P.S. also seen [Method 2](https://wiki.debian.org/Renaming_a_Package), but it seems only works on `dist-upgrade` (not tested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not *supposed* to work on `apt-get upgrade`. The reason is that it's not a straight-forward upgrade. In this case, `apt` has to remove `package_a` and install `package_b` for it to do an "upgrade", and apt will only do direct upgrades (new version of an installed package and any additional dependencies *installed*) when running `apt-get upgrade`.

`apt-get dist-upgrade`, on the other hand, will allow removals of a package to satisfy dependencies and upgrade packages, which is what you would have to do here.

Also, if you specify `package_a (<< 1.0)`, this will not match `package_a` with a version of `1.0`, and apt probably won't install `package_b`.

Comment: So the only possible way for debian/ubuntu do handle this is method 2? (Fixed 1.0 -> 1.1, spelling error)

Comment: If method 2 is `apt-get dist-upgrade`, then yes.

Comment: Method 2 is creating a third dummy package. looks `dist-upgrade` also ignores this package.

Comment: If you mean making `package_a` contain nothing except have a dependency on `package_b` (also known as a transition package or a metapackage), then that should work with `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Thx a lot, will test this. Thought that deb has something similar than rpm's `Obsoletes`

Comment: So short answer, not possible for my case. Cause I've to replace one package with two others (each for a different language). So method 2 will not work in this case.